# on mobile.changepage external HTML file requiring page refresh

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, refresh, external

I've been searching the solution for this issue for many days.
1st Splash Page have time out duration then it loads the the home page with list of links. The links are showing but the icons (awesome-icons) are not loading and the transition that i  set on each **li** is not loading as well.
once the page is loaded, if i refresh it all the content with the transition effects are working. I'm using animate.css for list animation.

Can someone figure out the issue?

**SPLASH PAGE CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Splash</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myapp.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).on('pageinit','#splash',function(){ 
      // the .on() method does require jQuery 1.7 + but this will allow you to have the contained code only run when the #splash page is initialized.
        setTimeout(function(){
            //$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "home.html", {transition: "animated fadeOut"});
            $.mobile.changePage("home.html", "animated fadeOut");
        }, 4000);
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="splash">
        <div data-role="content">
            <img src="images/uos_logo.svg" alt="startup image" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />
        </div>
    </div>


<!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

**HOME PAGE CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myapp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="home">        
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="myTabs" class="animated slideInUp">
                <li class="clr1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 1</a></li>
                <li class="clr2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 2</a></li>
                <li class="clr3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 3</a></li>
                <li class="clr4"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 4</a></li>
                <li class="clr5"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 5</a></li>
                <li class="clr6"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 6</a></li>
                <li class="clr7"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 7</a></li>
                <li class="clr6"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 8</a></li>
                <li class="clr5"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 9</a></li>
                <li class="clr4"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 10</a></li>
                <li class="clr3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 11</a></li>
                <li class="clr2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 12</a></li>
                <li class="clr1"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 13</a></li>
                <li class="clr2"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 14</a></li>
                <li class="clr3"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 15</a></li>
                <li class="clr4"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> 16</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- /page -->


<script type="text/javascript">
    $('ul#myTabs li').each(function(i){
    var t = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){ t.addClass('animated slideInUp'); }, (i+1) * 120);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default jQM loads pages into the current DOM via AJAX and only gets the first DIV with data-role="page". So any scripts/css in the second page are not loaded.

As you intention is to completely replace the splash with the first page, you could just use

```
location.assign("home.html");
```

If you really want the nice transition, just include the splash page within your first page as a separate data-role="page" div, or include all the scripts from home within the data-role="page" div so they get loaded into the dom.

Comment: Thank you, That really helped.